# Firebase Realtime database multidata adding using web

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem with firebase Realtime database using html/js.
I'm trying to add a data like a colours of pattern but every time it overwrites the same node for example.

```
Patterns
     Monopattern
        colour: white
```

when I try to add colour black it overwrite the white to black I'm searching for a way to set a specific name to name "colour" to add it as a child of the Monopattern.

```
function add_colours(){
            set(ref(db,"Patterns/"+ patt_name.value),{
                Colour : patt_color.value
            })
            .then(()=>{
               alert("success");
            })
            .catch(()=>{
               alert("Unsuccessful addition, error:"+error);
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new node under the pattern name, you can use the `push` function like this:

```
set(push(ref(db,"Patterns/"+ patt_name.value)),{
    Colour : patt_color.value
})
```

Every time you call `push()`, Firebase generates a unique key under the path you specify.